# error while loading shared libraries: libXau.so.6

Tags: ssh, x11

after restarting my machine, when I try connect with ssh I get this message :

```
/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth: error while loading shared libraries: libXau.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is a problem with symbolics libs, I fixed as root with

```
 ldconfig
```

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.